# Traefik. Раздел docker. Инструкция domain

Tags: docker, traefik

Зачем в [traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/), в разделе docker, есть параметр `domain`? Я в доке не нашёл, зачем это [нужно](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.4/configuration/backends/docker/). Смотрел разные версии, но так и не понял.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Написано

```
# Default domain used.
# Can be overridden by setting the "traefik.domain" label on a container.
#
# Required
#
domain = "docker.localhost"
```

Т.е. если ты указываешь на каждом контейнере метку traefik.domain, то это значение по умолчанию можешь игнорировать
Если же метки нет - оно берется из этого параметра конфигурации traefik.

Дальше смотри

```
traefik.frontend.rule=EXPR  Override the default frontend rule. Default: Host:{containerName}.{domain} or Host:{service}.{project_name}.{domain} if you are using docker-compose
```

Здесь пишут, что если ты не задаешь `frontend.rule`, то по умолчанию контейнер получит доменное имя `{имя_контейнера}.{то что прописано в traefik.domain}`

С чем соглашусь - в документации это описано как-то очень мудрено и запутанно.

См. также ответ на английском SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51887931/what-is-the-different-between-traefik-domain-and-traefik-frontend-rule-host

Comment: В вопросе на английском SO ровно тот вопрос, который мне нужен. Но либо сейчас времени много и я не понимаю поэтому, что там написано. Либо там написано что-то непонятное, дейсвительно.